# Asking python to print Unicode

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to make a python program that takes a character from the user and in the output window it will show its Unicode Value  When I searched this on the web it gave me this code as a result

```
print(u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f')
```

Which was opposite to my question
So what is the way to take a character and show the Unicode value

Comment: Ok from next time I will never ask questions on StackOverflow rather I can ask somewhere else do not take it as threat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def str_to_unicode(s: str):
     return s.encode("unicode_escape").decode()
 
str_to_unicode('Россия')
'\\u0420\\u043e\\u0441\\u0441\\u0438\\u044f'

print(str_to_unicode('Россия'))
\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is working fine but you should add print at the call of the function like this:-print(str_to_unicode('Россия'))

Answer (score 1):

```py
unicode_char = "Ó"
print(unicode_char.encode("unicode_escape")
```